# C# Is this a List or an Interface or something entirely different?

Tags: c#, interface

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople();
}
```

Was in the process of learning C# when I came across this method skeleton. Forgive me if this is a silly question, but what is the return type of this method? In other words, what is `IEnumerable<Person>?`

List, interface, list of interfaces, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is the interface, which Lists etc implement
Its similar to a IList, but its not the same.
U know its an interface because of the "I" in the name

Comment: Is there an advantage over declaring IEnumerable<Person> as opposed to List<Person>?

Answer (score 0):

`IPersonRepository` is an interface.
Its content is the function `GetPeople()` that returns an object of the type  `IEnumerable<Person>`.
`IEnumerable<>` is a generic interface, here used in a concrete implementation with the class `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is a Generic Collection, which has a type Person. So your method GetPeople() returns a list of Person objects. IPersonRepository is an interface, so any implementing class will have a method GetPeople().

Example using a List, which implement IEnumerable:

```
class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository{
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople() {
        var people = new List<Person>();
        people = // Wherever you get them from.
        return people;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. However, I am still confused about one thing. You said "your method GetPeople() returns a list of Person objects."  However, can you conclude that an IEnumerable<Person> is always a List of People objects? Could it also be another data structure, perhaps a Dictionary, Stack, Queue (I'm not too familiar with data structures yet)? I wasn't sure if you meant list in the programming sense.

Comment: And yes, it could be a Stack, Queue, or a Linked List. A Dictionary wouldn't match as it implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.

This is one of the reasons to return IEnumerable<T> from repositories, it allows you to do things with it elsewhere and doesn't tie you down to an implementation. I just used a List as an example.

Comment: Strictly speaking, GetPeople() returns anything which implements the IEnumerable interface for type Person. I see you're learning, so I suggest you have a look at how to implement IEnumerable in your own classes, then have a look at how this works with a Generic IEnumerable. There's quite a few tutorials online, and it's usually covered in books on C#.